# How to compare to dataframes and return matching and non matching

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have 2 data frames with the same length size. I'm trying to match the first 3 with the other data frame and then the next 3 and so on and so on. Hopefully I'm making sense.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1    = pd.DataFrame([[100,1,2,4,5,6,8],
                       [87,1,6,20,22,23,34],
                       [99,1,12,13,34,45,46],
                       [64,1,10,14,29,32,33],
                       [55,1,22,13,23,33,35],
                       [66,1,6,7,8,9,10],
                       [77,1,2,3,5,6,8],
                       [811,1,2,5,6,8,10], 
                       [118,1,7,8,22,44,56]],                        
                       columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])


df2    = pd.DataFrame([[89,2,4,6,8,10,12],
                       [81,2,7,25,28,33,54],
                       [91,2,13,17,33,45,48],
                       [66,2,20,24,25,36,38],
                       [56,1,24,33,43,53,65],
                       [78,3,14,15,18,19,20],
                       [120,4,10,23,25,26,38],
                       [59,5,22,35,36,38,40], 
                       [125,1,17,18,32,44,56]],
                       columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

I would like my result to like this

```
   match = pd.DataFrame([[100,89,2,4,6,8],
       [100,81,2,],
       [100,91,2],
       [87,89,6],
      [99,89,12],
      [64,56,1,43],
      [64,78,14],
      [55,56,1,33],
      [77,59,5],
      [811,59,5],
      [118,59,22],
      [118,125,1,44,56]],
      columns = ['Id','Id','Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

Comment: Your expected dataframe is invalid. Can you correct the expected output?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate what you mean by `I'm trying to match the first 3`? Thanks!

Comment: I would to see if id's 100, 87, 99 matches 89,91,81 and 64 ,55, 66 matches 66,56,78 and 77, 811, 118, matches 120, 59,125

Comment: Why is 87 matching only 89 then? How does this pattern continue for rows from dataframe 1 and rows from dataframe 2?

Comment: My bad I wasn't finish writing

Comment: ohk, and when you say. `100, 87, 99` matches `89,91,81`, you mean all possible combinations of the 3*3 rows right? so try matching 100, 89.. then 100, 91, then 100, 81, then 87, 89 then 87, 91 etc. is that correct?

Comment: Another question, what happens if one dataframe doesnt have number of rows that are multiples of 3. how would the matching behave then?

Comment: I would like it to return the matching values

Comment: Yes thats correct. 64  matches 66,56,78 and 77, 811, 118, matches 120, 59,125

Comment: Yes thats correct and then 64  matches 66,56,78 and 55 matches 66, 56, 78, and 66 matvhes 66, 56, 78 and 77 matches 120, 59, 125, and 811 matches 120,59,125 and 118 matches 120,59,125.